# Highlight last RibbonButton

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm

How can I highglight last button that was clicked so that user makes sure the right content is shown? (I would like have 1 button highlighted for specific content until another is clicked).

I am using ribbon *(System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon)*. 
The buttons which should highlight are held inside RibbonGroup and they are for changing the main content.

Other buttons should behave normally(I would like to limit number of buttons that are highlighted after click)

I use Model-View-ViewModel pattern

```
    <Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="top">
            <RibbonTab Header="Home">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Process Flow">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RibbonButton Label="Style change" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/StyleChange.png"></RibbonButton>
                        <RibbonButton Label="Settings" Command="{Binding ChangeToSettingContentCommand}" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Settings.png"></RibbonButton>
                        <RibbonButton Label="Firmware changes" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Code.png"></RibbonButton>
                        <RibbonButton x:Name="testsButton" Label="Tests" Command="{Binding ChangeToTestContentCommand}" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/test.png"></RibbonButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </RibbonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by binding HighLightSettingButton property and BorderBrush

```
<RibbonButton Label="Settings" BorderBrush="{Binding HighLightSettingButton, Converter={StaticResource brs}}" Command="{Binding ChangeToSettingContentCommand}" LargeImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Settings.png"></RibbonButton
```

and the implementation of Border Brush is

```
    public class BrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if ((bool)value == true) {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);                 
            //return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFFFEBAA"));
        } else
        return null;
    }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

 }
```